# Changing AJAX undefined variables so that post will work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have some conditional variables in the following code.  For example, if the var shipping == "true", then shippingAddress1, shippingAddress2, etc exist.  But, if shipping == "false", these variables are undefined, and left blank.  My problem is that when I try to post, I get a js error because some of the vars are undefined.  Is there any way send these through blank?

```
$.post( 'reserveAPickupAppointmentCreatePickup.php', {
    'location': appointmentLocation,
    'appointmentAddress1': appointmentAddress1,
    'appointmentAddress2': appointmentAddress2,
    'serviceType': serviceType,
    'shipping': shipping,
    'shippingAddress1': shippingAddress1,
    'shippingAddress2': shippingAddress2,
    'shippingCity': shippingCity,
    'shippingState': shippingState,
    'shippingZip': shippingZip,
    'startTime': startTime,
    'endTime': endTime,
    'date': date,
    'estimatedSize': appointmentSize,
    'highValueItems': highValueItems,
    'insuredItems': insuredItems,
    'tools': tools,
    'presentAtAppointment': presentAtAppointment,
    'contactName': contactName,
    'contactPhone': contactPhone,
    'contactEmail': contactEmail,
    'itemList': itemList,
    'studentPhone': studentPhone
},
```

Comment: If you are looking up form fields, use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set reasonable defaults for the variables you're using. If it's a string, default it to an empty string. In general don't use variables if they haven't been defined at some point.

Comment: So I have to do this one by one at the point that I define each variable?  I was hoping for a way to catch all of them at the same time and set them to an empty string...and I assume I just set an empty string by setting it equal to "" correct?

Comment: I would do it where you declare each variable. I generally declare all my variables at the top of my lexical scope and define them at the same time with reasonable defaults. Yes, an empty string would just be "" or ''

Comment: thanks, I ended up using this method, thanks for your help!  if I did it all at once at the end, I would need to write several conditional statements, and this was just easier.

Answer (score 2):

Add them dynamically:

```
var data = {
    location: appointmentLocation,
    appointmentAddress1: appointmentAddress1,
    appointmentAddress2: appointmentAddress2,
    serviceType: serviceType,
    shipping: shipping
    // etc.
};

if(shipping) {
    data.shippingAddress1 = shippingAddress1;
    data.shippingAddress2 = shippingAddress2;
    // etc.
}

$.post('reserveAPickupAppointmentCreatePickup.php', data);
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion, but there are way too many conditions

Comment: @radleybobins: Eh... no, doesn't look like it. Do what you're doing already and wrap the shipping-specific ones in the `if` as demonstrated. It's not very difficult.

Comment: I will certainly keep this in mind if I have less conditionals, but there were several cases...the shipping was just an example...I ended up just going back and defining the variables as empty strings, which should work find for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be declaring all your variables, but you can always do something like:

```
'foo' : foo || null,
...
```

Not sure if `$.post` will like that.

Comment: I'm not sure either, but it is worth a try